# Break when value encountered

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

Okay, I'm going out on a limb here, because I'm not sure this functionality exists, but if it doesn't, it probably should.  Here's what I know:

Somewhere in the code, a chunk of data is read in.  I'm trying to find that part of the code. (And we're talking a HUGE code-base here - tens of thousands of files in almost 300 projects.  Couldn't even begin to guess at lines of code - 2000-3000 per file is not uncommon, so this is real needle/haystack territory.)  I know that this data contains a specific identifiable string.  I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint for when **any** chunk of memory is set to that string.

What I don't know:

I have no idea where or even if this string is being stored anywhere, so I can't set a breakpoint on a memory address or a variable.  All I know is that for at least a brief period of time (perhaps no more than the scope of one function, or even just one iteration of a for loop), this value exists *somewhere*.  It's possible the string itself is ignored by the code and only the accompanying data is stored, but the string must exist in memory at some point.

I obviously can't set a regular breakpoint, because if I knew where to put that breakpoint, I'd already have what I need and there'd be no need to resort to such measures.  I don't even know what project this code occurs in, let alone what file or what function within that file - that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Is this just wishful thinking?  Or is there some easy way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: This functionality doesn't exist, and I don't think it's even feasible. Just think how much stress that would put on the debugger - checking all the memory all the time for a specific value...

Comment: It wouldn't need to check all the memory all the time.  Only when memory is actually changed, and then only the memory that was changed would need to be checked.  Yes it would result in slower performance, but it's debug mode so that's expected anyhow.  And the process could be sped up with all kinds of optimizations - I'm looking for a string of `X` length, but this command only changed `X-Y` bytes, so no need to monitor it, etc.  I don't think it'd be impossible to create such a tool, and it'd be extraordinarily useful...

Comment: I think if I really *had* to do that thing I would use Microsoft "detours" to hook ReadFileEx. Never used it though. For ref., it worked to just google that phrase.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying, "I have a problem X, and technology Y could fix it. Does Y exist?". If it turns out that Y does not exist, it may be useful to post a follow-up question, "I have a problem X, how can I solve it? Technology Y would fix it but it doesn't exist".

Comment: Explaining what it is I actually need would require too much info to post in a question like this, and possibly break NDA in the process.  I just wanted to put feelers out there to see if something like this actually existed, possibly as a 3rd-party plug-in if not built into VS?  If this leads nowhere though, I might try to phrase what I'm trying to do in some way that makes sense without overloading people/getting me in trouble.

Comment: @Alf - Just looked up Detours - seems like it *might* work, but it's not cheap - I'd have to check if we have a company license already for it, but if not I doubt they'd be willing to shell out on my account.  Also not sure if that'd be compatible with our loading system - most of that kind of stuff is in-house proprietary, and we're dealing mainly with game consoles (360, PS3), which don't use standard Windows file systems, so that may be a bit of a garden path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Process Monitor from Microsoft (was SysInternals) to monitor file I/O. If you have symbols configured correctly (yours and Microsoft's) then Process Monitor will display the stack traces associated with each file I/O operation.

Comment: I feel like this _might_ work.  Tricky part is I'm not dealing with the Windows file system on my computer, but rather the XBox file system on a dev-kit, so really I'd have to monitor network traffic instead, since it's not running locally.  Might take me a while to figure out how to filter all this info in, so I'm going to go ahead and accept this for the time being.

Comment: Yes.  It's even connected to the VS debugger, so they must be talking to each other somehow.  The data presumably lives on the XBox somewhere, but not in an easily accessible form.  The problem now is filtering down Process Monitor to a reasonable level - I'm afraid this may end up just being another needle in a different haystack.  Not sure how to search this input for a given string yet, or even if said string would ever appear in here - haven't found anything recognizable yet.

Comment: If the string is sent over the network and the communication is not encrypted, then you could use NetMon to find which packet the string is in. You could then get this packet's src and dest ports and its size and try to map it back to a network event in Process Monitor (which was running at the same time as NetMon). If you find the network event in Process Monitor you could then view the stack and see if any of your functions are there.

Comment: That first "if" is the big one, I think.  Pretty sure there's no encryption going on, but I'm not sure on what level the XBox is communicating directly with VS.  The data may exist only in the XBox's memory, and never be sent out to where it can be viewed by VS.  Problem is that so many thousands of events spam the window that it's difficult to pick out the one I care about - assuming it even exists...